# Parse facebook login crashing objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to have my app login with facebook but it keeps crashing from the parse and facebook developers [guild](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-twitter-users). Here is the code I have.

```
-(IBAction)LoginWithFacebook {
    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"email", @"password", @"user_about_me", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
    }];



   }
```

This is the error message I get when it crashes. It is long and I do not know what all of it means and I am not sure if this is helpful or not.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:openWithBehavior:fromViewController:completionHandler:] called!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011301ed85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001129c4deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011301ecbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f6dcfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f6d8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   RestaurentApp                       0x000000010f136b13 -[PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider authenticateAsync] + 627
    6   RestaurentApp                       0x000000010f133ffb +[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissionsInBackground:] + 122
    7   RestaurentApp                       0x000000010f134103 +[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:block:] + 71
    8   RestaurentApp                       0x000000010f0fcf90 -[LoginWithVC LoginWithFacebook] + 176
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000110fd8a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    10  UIKit                               0x000000011114be67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    11  UIKit                               0x000000011114c143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011114b263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    13  UIKit                               0x000000011104b99f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    14  UIKit                               0x000000011104c6d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110ff7dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000110fd1553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f44301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f3a22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f396e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f390f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114282ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000110fd6f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    23  RestaurentApp                       0x000000010f122aaf main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011374e92d start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: You may wish to include the crash information too.  No one is going to guess.

Comment: is your facebook app  public and available to all users ?

Comment: I will make sure to check @MuhammadAdnan

Comment: @Avi all it does is crash there is no way I can call the error in a nslog but I will provide what I get in the logs

Comment: Make sure you have the exception breakpoint enabled.

Comment: @Avi I have never used break points much do I just put on were?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that you are using a library too old, I had the same problem.

These are the two main steps:

1. Use ***ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework*** instead of *ParseFacebookUtils.framework*
2. Change the *logInWithPermissions* method to ***logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions***